# How to wrap multiple lines text with one div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

This is the HTML produced dynamically by a CMS:

```
<DIV CLASS="messageContent">
<BLOCKQUOTE CLASS="messageText">
<IMG ALT="image" CLASS="myimage" SRC="http://...."  STYLE="">
<BR> and more recently with desktop publishing<b> software like Aldus PageMaker/<b>including versions of Lorem Ipsum
</BLOCKQUOTE>
</DIV>
```

I tried to wrap the whole text with a div using this function:

```
$('blockquote.messageText').contents()
.filter(function(){return this.nodeType === 3})
.wrap('<div />');(found it in http://stackoverflow.com/ but don't remember where)
```

However, the above function wrap too many elements in div and even wrap empty space, the result looks like this:

```
<DIV CLASS="messageContent">
<div> </div>
<BLOCKQUOTE CLASS="messageText">
<IMG ALT="image" CLASS="myimage" SRC="http://...."  STYLE="">
<BR>
<div>   and more recently with desktop publishing </div>
<b> software like Aldus PageMaker/<b>
<div>including versions of Lorem Ipsum</div>
</BLOCKQUOTE>
</DIV>
```

So How can I wrap only the text in one div ?
This is the expected HTML:

```
<DIV CLASS="messageContent">
<BLOCKQUOTE CLASS="messageText">
<IMG ALT="image" CLASS="myimage" SRC="http://...."  STYLE="">
<DIV>
<BR> and more recently with desktop publishing<b> software like AlduPageMaker/<b>including versions of Lorem Ipsum
</DIV>
/BLOCKQUOTE>
</DIV>
```

Comment: What criterion would you be using to distinguish between the elements you want to include in the div and those you don't want to include? In your example, <BR> is included, but <IMG> isn't. What's the logic behind this?

Comment: Is it just the <IMG> tags you want to leave out, like @j08691 seems to be thinking?

Comment: The function split the text in many divs if <b> tag or <br> is present ,it wrap also empty space before <img>, the software output text dynamically, so HTML can be different.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the structure is as you have it in your example, you could use:

```
var img = $('blockquote.messageText img');
$('blockquote.messageText img').remove()
$('blockquote.messageText').wrapInner('<div>').prepend(img);
```

Which would generate:

```
<div class="messageContent">
    <blockquote class="messageText">
        <img alt="image" class="myimage" src="http://...." style="">
        <div>
            <br>and more recently with desktop publishing<b> software like Aldus PageMaker</b>including versions of Lorem Ipsum</div>
    </blockquote>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cV8Xu/4/)**

Comment: Thanks, this a partial fix, as I still get unwanted divs, before and after <br> or <b>.